# How much time it will take to insert 10 millions records in postgrerds database table

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary, for-loop, sql-insert

I have 11814568 record in csv file with two column, I encrpted 1st col in 8246 sec using in memory buffer ram
Now I have 9979561 records corresponding to 1st col as primary key and I have to insert or update 2nd col VALUE based on 1st column
I am using 128GB RAM configuration

Comment: Depending on the configuration and how often you do this, you could also use PostgreSQL commands directly; it has native tools to import CSV.

Comment: Can you garnish that question with table definitions and SQL statements?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? It's not clear if you want to import data or update existing data

Comment: Use COPY to import the CSV: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/populate.html#POPULATE-COPY-FROM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use chunks while inserting. Make your chunk size 1000 and insert them. I did it on 1M rows, it took 14 seconds. For 10M rows, it should take couple of minutes.

My chunk looks like:

```
INSERT INTO table(c1, c2)
VALUES (1,1), (2,2), (3,3) ... (1000, 1000)
```

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible code where multiple values you are inserting in chunks

Comment: From Dictionary